# Static content not loading in spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I recently updated my spring version from 2.5.5 to 2.5.6 which upgraded my spring-webflux dependency from 5.3.10 to 5.3.12. After this the static content is not loading. I assume there is a bug in this version.

I have a custom WebFluxConfigurer class which loads via resourceHandler and resourceLocation. Apparently after this upgrade it stopped working.

```
 @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/home/gecloud/dist/").resourceChain(true)
```

Is there a workaround. For now I am running with spring boot 2.5.6 but overrided the webflux version to older one.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.10</version>
        </dependency>
```